# React Hooks useEfffect

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react hooks, I have created below simple increment and decrement counter app.
What I want is that whenever the user clicks on the Increment or Decrement Button it should show the value in the alert Box.

After writing `useEffect` when the app launches I am getting an alert before clicking the Increment and Decrement Button.

One approach I know is that I can add the condition in `useEffect` when the value of the counter is greater than zero(alert>0), but that's not what I am looking for, I want some generic solution.

Alert should call only when the user Clicks on Increment and Decrement Button and we should use hooks.

```
const Counter = () =>{
const [value, setValue]= useState(0)

useEffect(()=>{
  displayAlert()
},[displayAlert])

function displayAlert(){
  alert(value)
}
  return(
    <>
    <p>Counter : {value}</p>
    <input type="button" value="Increment" onClick={()=>setValue(value+1)}/>
    <input type="button" value="Decrement" onClick={()=>setValue(value-1)}/>
    </>
  )
}
export default Counter
```

Comment: i have tried that but its still showing message before clicking the button.

Comment: Can you provide the sample code.. removing call from from useEffect, then how it will show the alert

Comment: Yeah that code is not showing the alert when I click the Increment or Decrement button. I need to show the value in alert only when user click on Increment or Decrement button.

Comment: I found another way use Use Ref.. It works as expected

Comment: `import React,{useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";

const Counter = () =>{
const [value, setValue]= useState(0)

const isFirstRun = useRef(true);
useEffect(()=>{
  
  if (isFirstRun.current) {
    
    isFirstRun.current = false;
    
    return;
  }
  displayAlert()
},[value])

function displayAlert(){
  alert(value)
}
  return(
    <>
    <p>Counter : {value}</p>
    <input type="button" value="Increment" onClick={()=>setValue(value+1)}/>
    <input type="button" value="Decrement" onClick={()=>setValue(value-1)}/>
    </>
  )
}
export default Counter`

Answer (score 1):

Even if you put `value` as a dependency for useEffect, it will show the alert the first time you load the page (when `value` gets its initial value of 0). I propose creating a function that changes `value` and displays the alert, and calling that from `onClick`:

```
function changeAndDisplayValue(newValue){
  setValue(newValue);
  alert(newValue);
}
```

You call `alert(newValue)` and not `alert(value)` because `setValue()` works asynchronously, so it may not yet have finished when `alert` is called (therefore `value` may still have the old value).

Then your buttons are like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Increment" onClick={()=>changeAndDisplayValue(value+1)}/>
<input type="button" value="Decrement" onClick={()=>changeAndDisplayValue(value-1)}/>
```

Comment: I am aware about this approach, but I need to solve this with hooks only

Answer (score 1):

There's react-use library that does provide a use "update" hook. https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useUpdateEffect.md

Check out their implementation:

- https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useUpdateEffect.ts
- https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/src/useFirstMountState.ts

Comment: Thanks, Japjappedulap this resolves the issue.. But any other way to stop initial render with useEffect

Comment: `useEffect` doesn't provide any "native" way of doing that as it's the established component lifecycle. If you check the implementation, it's a very simple ref used to track the initial render. The react-use library have a lot of small, useful hooks for controlling lifecycle and more. You can check out their implementations as it's very good educational material on hooks. Also, https://github.com/Wavez/react-hooks-lifecycle takes a dive into functional component lifecycle

Answer (score 0):

I believe MORÈ means this:

```
const Counter = () =>{
const [value, setValue]= useState(0)

useEffect(()=>{
  displayAlert()
},[value])

function displayAlert(){
  alert(value)
}
  return(
    <>
    <p>Counter : {value}</p>
    <input type="button" value="Increment" onClick={()=>setValue(value+1)}/>
    <input type="button" value="Decrement" onClick={()=>setValue(value-1)}/>
    </>
  )
}
export default Counter
```

Comment: Its still showing the value zero in alert, before clicking the Increment and Decrement Button.

Comment: Check out this stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kqhts1?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2FCounter.jsx

Answer (score 0):

Apart from conditional check in `useEffect` there is no way to prevent first call of `useEffect`. One other approach would be to have a separate `useEffect` and a state which would hold the `didMount` property. Initially `didMount` would be `false` and as soon as the `useEffect` runs it would convert `didMount` to `true`. Then on your original `useEffect` you would check if `didMount` is `true`, and only then call your function (alert)